# Is it possible to sue the German government because of a break with the IFG (TTIP)?

Tags: germany

The [Transatlantic Trade and Investment Partnership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transatlantic_Trade_and_Investment_Partnership) is heavily debated. It's [still debated behind closed doors](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/business/news/the-biggest-us-eu-free-trade-agreement-in-history-is-advancing-behind-closed-doors-10189919.html)! Citizens may not get a look at the documents; a few German politicians have - after a very long debate - been able to get a look at it; but they have had to look at it in the American Embassy, have to read it there under high security standards and may not talk about or duplicate the documents. I mean, that is just against democracy. And it's frightening that even elected politicians were unable to discuss it for a very long time, as they would have to sign on behalf of Germany.

I would like to know if it's possible to sue the German government for its lack of transparency. I mean, we have the [Federal Act Governing Access to Information held by the Federal Government](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_ifg/index.html), the German analogue to the US Freedom of Information Act:

> ### Section 1 Underlying principles
>
> (1) Everyone is entitled to official information from the authorities
>   of the Federal Government in accordance with the provisions of this
>   Act. This Act shall apply to other Federal bodies and institutions
>   insofar as they discharge administrative tasks under public law. For
>   the purposes of these provisions, a natural or legal person shall be
>   treated as equivalent to an authority where an authority avails itself
>   of such a person in discharging its duties under public law.
>
> (2) The authority may furnish information, grant access to files or
>   provide information in any other manner. Where an applicant requests a
>   certain form of access to information, the information may only be
>   provided by other means for good cause. In particular, substantially
>   higher administrative expenditure shall constitute good cause.
>
> (3) Provisions in other legislation on access to official information
>   shall take precedence, with the exception of Section 29 of the
>   Administrative Procedure Act (VwVfG) and Section 25 of Book Ten of the
>   Social Code.
>
> ### Section 2 Definitions
>
> For the purposes of this Act,
>
> 1. official information shall be defined as every record serving official purposes, irrespective of the mode of storage. This shall not
>      include drafts and notes which are not intended to form part of a
>      file;
> 2. a third person shall be defined as anyone on whom personal data or other information are held.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, of course you can bring this to a court: Generally, all decisions of the government are open to judicial review. You would have to try and request the information from the relevant authorities first; if (when) they reject your request, you can bring the matter before a *Verwaltungsgericht*. This is laid out in [§ 9](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/ifg/__9.html) (4) ([official but non-authoritative translation](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_ifg/englisch_ifg.html#p0054)) of the law.

It is quite unlikely that you would win, however, since the law contains a long list of exceptions in §§ 3 to 6. Of particular interest here is § 3 no. 3 a) (*necessary confidentiality of international negotiations*) and perhaps § 3 no. 1 a) (*detrimental effect on international relations*).

Comment: Thank you. It's sad :/ ... I would love to know more about it.

Comment: Bear in mind that this is just a negotiation at the moment. (But keep up pressure on your local politicians to make sure it stays that way)